# Groupby with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have data

```
 used_at  active_seconds  buy  
 2016-03-18 10:42:32       0  
 2016-03-18 10:42:34       1  
 2016-03-18 10:42:36       0  
 2016-03-18 10:42:38       1  
 2016-03-18 10:42:40       0  
 2016-01-18 10:42:42       0  
 2016-02-18 10:58:48       0  
 2016-03-18 11:00:13       1  
 2016-03-18 11:03:38       0
```

I need to print in result first string with buy = 1 and after it print string before it with the same month and `month - 1`. How can I specify it?
I know, that I can choose last and first data

```
df1 = df2.ix[df2.url.str.contains(id), 'date']
diff_date = (df1.iat[-1] - df1.iat[0])
```

But it's difference between two date. I want to get all data between dates

```
2016-03-18 10:42:34       1:
2016-03-18 10:42:32       0 
2016-03-18 10:42:38       1:
2016-03-18 10:42:32       0  
2016-03-18 10:42:34       1
2016-03-18 10:42:36       0
2016-03-18 11:00:13       1:
2016-02-18 10:58:48       0
2016-03-18 10:42:40       0
```

some string not print, because it number of month can be less, than number of month-1 where buy=1

Comment: @shivsn add to question